Is it appropriate to respond with a Content-Range header and HTTP status 206 ("partial content") when the client didn't request a range?
Our backend file delivery tends to be slow and our clients appear rather rude. They don't test the server for range support with HEAD / Accept-Ranges requests and they don't request reasonable ranges. Instead, they burst in requesting a whole video, sometimes for no other reason than to display a play button.
So I got the idea of responding with ranges / partial content to requests of large media files, even when the client did not request a range.
Our clients are standard browsers and our own client software with hosted WebView2 instances. So far this seems to be working well. I'd guess that range requests are a pretty basic feature and are widely supported. It is also acceptable to respond to a range request with a different range than the requested one. Or to respond with the complete content even though a range was requested.
However, I'm still worried that I'm asking for trouble with this approach. The RFC says that clients decide whether they support ranges and therefore range responses should only be delivered to range requests, which makes sense. Is that of any practical concern though? Should I just go with it because it seems to be working or is there a better solution to this problem?

Could you just respond with an error instead? I think it's usually better to use explicit behavior vs somewhat magic behavior.

@Evert Hm, but which error code would be appropriate? 416 / "Range Not Satisfiable" is only for range requests, 300 / "Multiple Choices" is not exactly the right thing either, 204 / "No Content" makes no sense because then I would rather use 206, which I already do. I couldn't find any more suitable error code.

Errors start with a 4 or 5. This one would fall in the 4 category. If there's no great fit for an error code, I would just fall back on 400 which is the generic error (and then you can add more details in the response body)

But we want to play nice. Not displaying the video because of a 400 error (or similar) is not an option. I'll just go with sending the unrequested ranges and see if anyone has any issues with that in practice. Thanks for your input though.
